# В данном случае тире или двоеточие после "никуда"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Без вёсел никуда() на ветер рассчитывать не стоит."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Без вёсел никуда: на ветер рассчитывать не стоит.** Двоеточие ставится по основному правилу, так как причина указана во второй части.

**Без вёсел никуда ― на ветер рассчитывать не стоит.** Тире заменяет двоеточие, если вторая часть имеет присоединительный характер (это решает автор).

В первом случае  в устной речи делается **увеличенная пауза**, предупреждающая о последующем пояснении. Во втором случае пауза имеет **меньшую длительность.**

Answer (score 2):

**Без вёсел никуда: на ветер рассчитывать не стоит.**

Пояснение.
Между частями бессоюзного предложения ставится двоеточие, если вторая часть указывает на причину того, что описано в первой части, например: В развитых странах средний класс решает исход выборов: он составляет большинство населения. В это предложение можно вставить союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО ([Знаки препинания между частями бессоюзного предложения](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185))

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что есть ещё один вариант "оформления" предложения.
Предположительно, в таком контексте:

— И куда же вы собрались?
— **Без вёсел — никуда, на ветер рассчитывать не стоит.**

Тире ставится на месте пропущенных членов, а запятая разделяет части сложного предложения.

Comment: Это не прямая речь.

Comment: А при чем здесь прямая речь? Ведь Ваше предложение тоже или кем-то сказано, или написано, или продумано, и его с лёгкостью можно оформить как чужие слова. Я имела в виду _другой смысл,_  поэтому и привела _возможный_ контекст.

Comment: Вы приводите свои, выдуманные примеры, когда есть конкретное предложение. Вопрос о конкретном предложении, в нём нет прямой речи.

Comment: Я ничего не выдумываю , я говорю о конкретном предложении. Хорошо, пусть будет так. В Вашем предложении вполне возможна такая пунктуация: **Без вёсел — никуда, на ветер рассчитывать не стоит.**

Comment: Обоснуйте, каким образом тире ставится перед "никуда", если по правилу должно стоять двоеточие после?

Comment: Я объяснила в ответе: тире ставится на месте пропущенных членов предложения. Без вёсел [не плывем] никуда, на ветер рассчитывать не стоит.

Comment: Тогда как быть с правилом? Выше Jasmin ответила. Игнорировать?

Comment: М_Г тоже привёл правило. Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно или несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов и заключающих в себе:
а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чем говорится в первом предложении и б) основание, причина того, о чем говорится в первом предложении.